# MvcContrib grid and checkboxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

Lets say I render a Checkbox:

```
@Html.CheckboxFor(x => x.Checked) // Checked is true by default
```

ASP will turn that as:

```
<input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The field is required." id="Checked" name="Checked" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="Checked" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

Since ASP outputs two inputs with the same name for a Checkbox, we also get two GET parameters in the URL when submitting the form with the checkbox:

```
http://...?Checked=true&Checked=false
```

Lets say I'm also using MvcContrib for displaying a table with sorting.

When I sort a column, MvcContrib is unable to understand the duplicate GET parameters, and instead of writing `?Checked=true&Checked=false`, it writes `?Checked=true%2Cfalse`, which can't be parsed to a bool by MVC3. The error message after sorting is:

```
String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.
```

Has anyone else experienced this problem with the MvcContrib grid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, think I have come up with the solution:

Create your own HtmlTableGridRenderer:

```
public class CustomTableGridRenderer<TViewModel> : HtmlTableGridRenderer<TViewModel> where TViewModel : class
{
    protected override void RenderHeaderText(GridColumn<TViewModel> column)
    {
        if (IsSortingEnabled && column.Sortable)
        {
            string sortColumnName = GenerateSortColumnName(column);

            bool isSortedByThisColumn = GridModel.SortOptions.Column == sortColumnName;

            var sortOptions = new GridSortOptions
            {
                Column = sortColumnName
            };

            if (isSortedByThisColumn)
            {
                sortOptions.Direction = (GridModel.SortOptions.Direction == SortDirection.Ascending)
                    ? SortDirection.Descending
                    : SortDirection.Ascending;
            }
            else //default sort order
            {
                sortOptions.Direction = column.InitialDirection ?? GridModel.SortOptions.Direction;
            }

            var routeValues = CreateRouteValuesForSortOptions(sortOptions, GridModel.SortPrefix);

            //Re-add existing querystring
            foreach (var key in Context.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Where(key => key != null))
            {
                if (!routeValues.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    routeValues[key] = Context.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString[key];
                }
            }

            var link = HtmlHelper.GenerateLink(Context.RequestContext, RouteTable.Routes, column.DisplayName, null, null, null, routeValues, null);
            RenderText(link);
        }
        else
        {
            base.RenderHeaderText(column);
        }
    }
}
```

... and just replace

```
                if(! routeValues.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    routeValues[key] = Context.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString[key];
                }
```

... with `routeValues[key] = Context.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString[key];`

And use your new rendering like so:

@Html.Grid()...RenderUsing(new CustomTableGridRenderer())

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after searching and trying a lot of different solutions, a simple change solved it. Just make sure to put this in your controller right before "return view":

```
 ModelState.Remove("Checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

Bad solution, but works:

```
 $(function() {
        $("a[href*='true%2Cfalse']").each(function () {
            $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href").replace("true%2Cfalse", "true"));
        });
    });
```

Please provide the other server-side solution.