# Checkbox and Hidden field in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, checkboxfor

`Html.CheckboxFor` generates hidden field with `false` value and it is reasonable. But now I need to implement form with GET HTTP method. Obviously true AND false values are being sent to the server when I submit my form. the problem is that MVC model binder cannot understand "true,false" value.

```
The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'System.Boolean' failed. 
See the inner exception for more information.
```

How can I workaround this issue?

Comment: Can you post code for your model, action, and view?  Is the property in the model a bool or string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was in MvcContribGrid.

See question: [MvcContrib grid and checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853599/mvccontrib-grid-and-checkboxes)

It combines query string values http://contoso.com?CheckBoxVal=true,CheckBoxVal=false into http://contoso.com?CheckBoxVal=true,false